# Colour Temperature and the thermal temperature

Tags: thermal-radiation, light-emitting-diodes

I understand that Colour Temperature correlates with the object's thermal temperature, such as a red-hot piece of iron being ~360c and the incandescent bulb filament is about 2500c.

**Why are sources of light, such as LEDs and florescent tubes, that emit white to white-blue light** (which according to Colour Temperature, would be around 4500+c) **cool, or nowhere near 4500c, when touched?**

Also, **why is the sky considered 10,000k? Especially if the surface of the sun is only ~5770k?**

Answer (score 3):

[Colour temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) isn't indicative of the temperature of the actual light source: it indicates the temperature at which an ideal *black-body* radiation source (i.e. opaque body which doesn't reflect light at all) would radiate a similar color. It's easy to understand that blue light is produced by objects with a higher temperature because that part of the electromagnetic spectrum corresponds to higher energies.

So when we say that the sky is $10\,000\ \rm K$, we don't mean that it's actually that hot: it's actually that an ideal black-body at $10\,000\ \rm K$ would radiate light of the same color. After that, you can read about [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) to describe why the sky is blue.